# Regular Expressions Finding A Set of Numbers

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am stumped on trying to figure out regular expressions so I thought I would ask the big dogs.

I have a string that can range from 1-4 sets as follows:

```
1234-abcd, baa74739, maps21342, 6789
```

Now I have figured out the regular expressions for the `1234-abcd`, `baa74739`, and `maps21342`. However, I am having trouble figuring out a code to pull the numbers that stand alone. Does anyone have an opinion on a way around this?

Example of the regex I used:

```
dbout.Range("D7").Formula = "=RegexExtract(DH7," & Chr(34) & "([M][A][P][S]\d+)" & Chr(34) & ")"
dbout.Range("D7").AutoFill Destination:=dbout.Range("D7:D2000")
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a regular expression to me.  Are you using excel?  A good place to play around with regular expressions is https://www.regexpal.com/ If you want to know how best to use them in excel, you're probably better off asking somewhere where people specialize in excel (or at least tagging your question accordingly).

Comment: `RegexExtract` is not `excel` nor `vba`. please update your tags.

Answer (score 0):

for digit stand alone replace

```
dbout.Range("D7").Formula = "=RegexExtract(DH7," & Chr(34) & "([M][A][P][S]\d+)" & Chr(34) & ")"
dbout.Range("D7").AutoFill Destination:=dbout.Range("D7:D2000")
```

with

```
dbout.Range("D7").Formula = "=RegexExtract(DH7," & Chr(34) & "(\b\d+\b)" & Chr(34) & ")"
dbout.Range("D7").AutoFill Destination:=dbout.Range("D7:D2000")
```

OR

```
dbout.Range("D7").Formula = "=RegexExtract(DH7,""(\b\d+\b)"")"
dbout.Range("D7").AutoFill Destination:=dbout.Range("D7:D2000")
```